# Derivative of an Area Preserving Operation

Tags: derivatives

Let z be in the complex domain.
Then define $\hat{z} = e^{j\theta}z$, where $\theta$ is a constant.
If the derivative is taken, by using the fact that rotation won't change the area (area preserving operation), can we say that $d\hat{z} = dz $?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is $\theta$ constant or supposed to be the argument of $z$? If constant, do you know how to compare dy and dx in y=(-1)*x?

Comment: Yes, $\theta$ is a constant. In this case $y = -x \rightarrow y=e^{-j\pi}x \rightarrow dy = -dx$, isn't it?. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat this as an extended comment, not really an answer.

I think you are confused here. Let $Z=Cz$ with $C\in \mathbb{C}$. Then $dZ = Cdz$ and this has nothing to do with "area". This is a simple differential (more along the lines of length, than area).

If you are actually interested in area, then $dx dy$ is what you are looking for. Then writing $z=x+iy$, $Z=X+iY$  and $C=a+ib$, you get
$$
X+iY=(ax-by)+i(ay+bx)
$$
Then using a Jacobian
$$
dX dY = |\begin{vmatrix}a & -b\\
b & a\end{vmatrix}| dxdy = (a^2+b^2) dxdy = |C|^2 dxdy
$$
Clearly, if $C=e^{i\theta}$, then the area element remains unchanged (as it should be).

Alternatively, if you insist on using $dz$ in relation to area, the area element is $dz d\overline{z}$. From which you can again see that $dZd\overline{Z}=|C|^2 dz d\overline{z}$.